# Best practices incoming object message inheritance using JAX-RS

Tags: java, inheritance, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I was wondering if there is a good solution to my problem, or is there good practices, on handling different messages from an object hierarchy.

So in short: I have an object hierarchy, lets say:

```
interface IMessage 
abstract Message implements IMessage
class SimpleMessage extends Message
class ReportMessage extends SimpleMessage
class CostReportMessage extends ReportMessage
class IncomeReportMessage extends ReportMessage
... (like 3 other types, similar to the CostReportMessage)
```

So what I would like is to have one incoming JAX-RS endpoint method, since most of the handler code is the same for the classes, but we need some conditional parts in the code.

E.g:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + "; charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8"})
public Response createReport(  final ReportMessage, @Context HttpHeaders headers ) {
...
...
}
```

So we have some methods like the one above, but I would like to make it one, like receive an incoming IMessage, and later handle it as the object's class needs it.

Do you have any advice on this problem? Or do you know any best practices, on how to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent class as the consumed object then copy all the properties using BeanUtils.copyProperties() to the new dedicated message object based on certain conditions, eg: you have messageTypeID variable in SimpleMessage to tell what kind of message it should be.

```
  @POST
  @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + "; charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8"})
  public Response createReport(  SimpleMessage message, @Context HttpHeaders headers ) {
       SimpleMessage convertedMessage;
       if(//condition//) {
           convertedMessage = new ReportMessage();
           BeanUtils.copyProperties(convertedMessage, message);
       } else { ... }
       ...
  }
```

Comment: Hmm.. Nice catch, I wil look into it.

Comment: It doesn't work, since the JAX-RS runtime will only know the SimpleMessage class, will consume that class, and won't know, the other part of the incoming message (e.g. it won't unmarshal the specifics of the CostReportMessage class).

Comment: Well if each specific message class has their own properties (object variables) then you can try using Object type in the method parameter, then convert it to certain message type class object based on certain condition (as i proposed) using reflection to 1 of the passed object's property

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't find the following solution "nice", or "elegant", but this seems to work:

step 1. create a function

```
private IMessage parseRequest(String request) throws IOException, JAXBException{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(request);
    // unmarshaller here is a simple JAXB Unmarshaller for the message package
    IMessage message = (SimpleMessage) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader); 
    return message;
}
```

step 2. modify jaxb entry point

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + "; charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8"})
public Response createReport(  final String request, @Context HttpHeaders headers ) {
    IMessage message = parseRequest(request);
    ...
    ...
    return response;
}
```

So I think, this is because of the following (and this is only my theory, but I don't know where to look for the truth):

1. JAX-RS simply checks for the type, and creates an Unmarshaller correspondent to the type given in the method signature.
2. JAX-RS will fail on giving IMessage in method param (since the interface doesn't have a constructor)
3. Since the Unmarshaller created by JAX-RS will only create a context, that is aware of SimpleMessage, it won't be able to unmarshal any child class, e.g. CostReportMessage
4. The good solution would be providing a custom MessageBodyReader (@Provider annotation), but I couldn't get it to work
5. This may be because of how the jersey finds a content provider for a given type (goes from the most generic to the most specific, and because it finds a more generic content provider, than mine, it won't use it)